# onmouseover function Javascript for changing the background of a section

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I was trying to write a function that changes the color of background of a section by going over it with the mouse - using 'onmouseover'. I was looking for similar question and tried the solutions that was offered but it did not work on my code.
Here is what i did:

```
function Rectangle(count){
var newRec = document.createElement("SECTION");
newRec.style.width="202px";
newRec.style.height="312px";
newRec.style.border="1px solid #3f3f3f";
newRec.style.background = "#FFFFFF";
newRec.style.display = "inline-block";
newRec.style.margin= "44px";
newRec.style.size= "50px";

var appendRec = function() {
    document.addEventListener("onmouseover", myFunction);
    document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(newRec);
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementTagName("SECTION").style.background = "#000000";
};


appendRec();     
};
```

Can anyone tell me what i did wrong?
And I was trying to work with the console but this code doesn't say anything is wrong...

Comment: Can you put your entire code snippet, it is important to how and where you have placed this snippet ..

Comment: what is `main` tag ?

Comment: `document.getElementTagName` does not exist, you should be using `document.getElementsByTagName`, this will also return an array of elements. Might I ask why you don't do this with `css`?

Comment: I changed it and added the By but it still doesn't work :/ and it is a requirement to use javascript

Comment: the tag main is where to locate the section that was created

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementTagName("SECTION").style.background = "#000000";` is wrong.

First, it's called `getElementsByTagName()`. And second, it returns an array, not just one element.

Solution: Give the `<section>` an `id` and use `getElementById()` instead.

Comment: I gave it id like that:  
         newRec.setAttribute("id", "myRec");
and then change it to:
            var appendRec = function() {
          document.addEventListener("onmouseover", myFunction);
                document.getElementsByTagName('main'[0].appendChild(newRec);
   };
 
       function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById('myRec').style.background="#000000";};

but it still not working.. any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
document.getElementById('WhichElementWillBeHoveredID').onmouseenter = function() {
  // when entering element...
}

document.getElementById('WhichElementWillBeHoveredID').onmouseleave = function() {
  // when leaving element
}
```

Sure... you can easily use CSS as well..

```
SELECTOR:hover { background-color: #444 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle to change background color and this is the only requirenment then I think it is good

http://jsbin.com/cagawa/edit?html,css,output

```
#mydiv{
  background: #cccccc;
}

#mydiv:hover{
  background: #ffdd00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try change

```
var appendRec = function() {
    document.addEventListener("onmouseover", myFunction);
    document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(newRec);
};
```

to

```
var appendRec = function() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('main')[0].appendChild(newRec);
    newRec.addEventListener("mouseover", myFunction);
};
```

I edited littlebit code, try now :)

Comment: it just colored the first section to black :/

Answer (score -1):

If im not wrong on line 12:
    document.addEventListener("onmouseover", myFunction);

should be replaced by

document.addEventListener("onmouseover",myFunction());